# Why my reflections are stretched?

Tags: edges, normals, bevel, matcaps, roughness

I've imported from Plasticity an OBJ, and even without Ngons I still got this mess at the angles of my mesh:
[image]

I've tried manipulate UVs, using a normal map and assign to the roughness attribute, using Normal edit and Weighted normal modifiers (Getting only bad results), reducing the face count, export the mesh with triangles or quads, remeshing and re-beveling the edges in Blender with a similar geometry (I was thinking that maybe Plasticity was the problem) getting the same results.
I don't get it why the reflections can't be continuous, and I constantly change between auto-smooth and smooth shading (Even if in this case is totally useless) because for what I seen elsewhere it's either a normal problem or a topology problem.
Here's other pics for better understanding:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: 2 suggestions 1: put in a loop inside the bevel, on the side of the large face, to ease the transition of normals between the last small face of the bevel an the large flat face.  2: Explore the _Weighted Normal_ modifier, by face area, while sliding the new loop. If this is taking you towards a normal interpolation you like, I'll pop in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

There's no issue here, that's exactly how this object would look in reality. If you find the "cutoff" too sharp, you can always soften the bevel a little bit (by using a custom bevel profile, for instance).

Answer (score -1):

I can’t be sure without seeing them but maybe the UV’s are stretched? I’d try a smart projection of the UV’s and if it fixes it then work on a more professional UV solution.

Comment: That's the first thing I tried to check. It seems not to be the cause.